# wait for child not working (roblox studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local find = script.Parent    
find.Touched:Connect(function(touched)
local de = find:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
if de == true then
    print("we found a human!")

end
```

end)

is not working?? I'm new to this but i just don't understand!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to detect when a player joins the game?

Comment: touch script is what im going for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your script is not functioning as intended is because `:FindFirstChild()` will return an object. (not a boolean)

So your statement is practically stating

```lua
local part = Instance.new("Part")
if part == true then -- Part does not equal true
```

The solution is quite simple. When `:FindFirstChild()` doesn't find anything it will return nil. So just make sure that it `~=~ nil

```lua
local find = script.Parent    
find.Touched:Connect(function(touched)
    local de = touched.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if de ~= nil then -- checking if a humanoid was found
        print("we found a human!")
    end
end)
```

Comment: its still unresponsive.

Comment: It should be `touched.Parent:FindFirstChild`

Comment: Edited to incorporate the fix that Kylaaa mentioned above @therealweldtool

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much I have been having this issue for 2 years..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to detect if a player was joined then Try use this code:

```
local find = game:GetService("Players")

find.PlayerAdded:Connect(function ()
    print("we found a human")
end)
```

Copy it into your LocalScript and place your LocalScript in StarterGui library

[Learn more about Players here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Players) -
[Learn more about LocalPlayer/Player here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player)

If that's not what you meant to, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Its a touch script. i edited the post and made it more advanced